# How do I select surrounding block

Tags: key-bindings

What is the command for Emacs/Spacemacs to select the surrounding (logical) block?

I know I've used this some time ago, I just don't remember how exactly :)

Answer (score 1):

Aah, found it, it's `expand-region.el` and in Spacemacs it's: select some line inside the region, then `SPC-v` and `v` to increase the region, `V` to contract it...